# how to resolve the error ts.(2345) in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

error -Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
there are 2 error in this code 1st in line no.27 and 2nd in line no.32.

Comment: Please share the code that generates this error.

Comment: Show the code where it happens, that isn't enough. I already know the error, but I need the code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Always share some code with it, its impossible to decode it for you. But the error happens in the following case:

```
let myVar = null;

// ..

myVar = 'assigned a string';
```

---

Solution: define the type for myVar to be:

```
let myVar: string|null
```

Answer (score 0):

your typescript error is telling you that you are trying to assign a variable of type `string | null` to a variable that expects a string instead. ex:

```js
let x : string | null = 'something'

function doSomething(foo: string) {
 ...
}

doSomething(x)
```

this is a simple example. For example, you can use the typescript guards:

```js
let x : string | null = 'something'

function doSomething(foo: string) {
 ...
}

if(typeof x === 'string') {
 doSomething(x)
}
```

[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) you can read about.

or you can type casting like:

```js
let x : string | null = 'something'

function doSomething(foo: string) {
 ...
}


doSomething(<string>x)
```

Typescript is strinct but will help you to avoid boring erros

Good Coding!